# Difficulty Configuring Insecure Registry in Rancher Desktop 1.12.3 on Windows. "http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client"

Tags: docker, docker-registry, rancher-desktop

When I tried to `docker login x.x.x.x:8081` it gives me following error
`Error response from daemon: Get "https://10.43.18.20:8081/v2/": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client`
In some places I read that adding a insecure registry will solve the problem. So I tried it but unable to locate the Docker daemon configuration file (/etc/docker/daemon.json) to configure the insecure registry.

I'm using Rancher Desktop version 1.12.3 on Windows and encountering difficulties setting up an insecure registry for Docker. Need assistance to understand how to configure Docker securely within Rancher Desktop on Windows. Planning to add insecure registry for plain HTTP communication.

Steps Taken:

1. Tried accessing /etc/docker/ directory in WSL terminal, but it doesn't exist.
2. Searched for the configuration file using find command without success.
3. Added `DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry=x.x.x.x:8081"` in `/etc/conf.d/docker` file, that won't work. also whenever I restart the docker it is getting removed.
4. Tried creating daemon.json file inside `<user>/.docker` folder and added following

```
{
  "insecure-registries":["x.x.x.x:8081"]
}
```

That also don't solve the problem.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Drop the `s` from the URI or configure the registry to use TLS.

Comment: Thank you for you valuable response. But dropping the `s` form URI doesn't work for me. Can you please provide some information on how to add a insecure registry?